# Redis crashing suddenly

Tags: magento2, redis

Anyone had a problem with Redis suddenly spiking and then crashing the server?  we have had a recurring problem with Magento2.  Redis suddenly gets hit with masses of data which makes it unavailable and it eventually crashes.

Comment: What version of m2? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10002

Answer (score 0):

Did you check dmesg / kern.log, to make sure it didn't get killed by the system OOM killer?

It is also possible, that you set up redis maxmemory to small and are hitting a memory limit inside redis.

If you really are getting hit with lots of data, you can use the monitor command inside redis-cli, to check out the data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is not hitting memory constraints but maxing the CPU at 100% but it is getting large objects suddenly.